# How to pull (null) records in Access database

Tags: ms-access

I would like to pull some records in an access database query where the the condition of the column is (null). Here is the sample records:

```
Drink column:
(null)
Pepsi
Tea
(null)
Ice Tea
(null)
```

I would like to pull those records that have the (null) values. Here are my queries so far but it did not return the desired result.

```
SELECT PRODUCT.DRINK
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE (((PRODUCT.DRINK) Is Null));



SELECT PRODUCT.DRINK
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE (((PRODUCT.DRINK)=(Null)));
```

My desired result is:

```
Drink:
(null)
(null)
(null)
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: have u tried in this way..
select * from product where drink is null

Comment: @LuckyBoy Using * to select all fields is generally discouraged, and should not be necessary.

Comment: And you don't need all those brackets unless you've got multiple conditions:
`WHERE PRODUCT.DRINK IS NULL` should work fine.

Comment: @Bridge Those brackets are just what Access does in query design, if you take them out, they will just be put back.

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE (((PRODUCT.DRINK) Is Null));` is correct. What is going wrong for you?

Does you table allow zero length fields? If so, you will need to allow for that

```
WHERE PRODUCT.DRINK Is Null  Or PRODUCT.DRINK = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked perfect on my system.

```
SELECT PRODUCT.DRINK
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE (PRODUCT.DRINK Is null);
```

Comment: @ Mujtaba, I tried this too. It returns some blank records. I was looking for those (null) records. I checked the Allow Zero Length in the drink column and it is set as Yes. Still debugging the issue. Thanks very much